# Moodle LDAP integration - LDAP-module cannot connect to any servers

Tags: active-directory, ldap, moodle

I managed to get my Active Directory up and running, and now I want to integrate my MS-AD into my Moodle server. I followed the steps from the Moodle docs as close as I can.

This is the error message I get when trying to log into my Moodle server with an Active Directory User:

```
LDAP-module cannot connect to any servers: Server: 'ldap://europe.domain.com/', Connection: 'Resource id #16', Bind result: ''
```

And here is my LDAP server configuration within Moodle:

***LDAP server settings***
**Host URL:** ldap://europe.domain.com/
**Version:** 3
**Use TLS:** No

***Bind settings***
**Distinguished name:** cn=ldap-user,dc=europe,dc=domain,dc=com

***User lookup settings***
**User type:** MS ActiveDirectory
**Contexts:** ou=moodleusers,dc=europe,dc=domain,dc=com

Thats what I have done so far:

- Created "moodleusers" OU
- Created ldap-user AD user account & set the password to "Password never expires."

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possible answer here in the Moodle forums

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=427908#p1722336

> Bind result normally refers to two things.
>
> 1. Your bind user is entered incorrectly (perhaps an expired or changed password)
> 2. Your bind user does not have the necessary permissions on the OU referenced in the context.

Maybe also try one of the LDAP tools to test the connection outside of Moodle

https://ldap.com/ldap-tools/

For example

http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page